# Problem with update state in React with Intersection observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

```js
import {
  Box
} from '@mui/material';
import {
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState
} from 'react';

export const patientResults = {
  items: [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      dob: '1990-05-15'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Alice',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      dob: '1985-12-28'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Bob',
      lastName: 'Johnson',
      dob: '1993-08-03'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Emma',
      lastName: 'Brown',
      dob: '1988-02-17'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'David',
      lastName: 'Williams',
      dob: '1995-11-09'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Olivia',
      lastName: 'Jones',
      dob: '1982-06-25'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Michael',
      lastName: 'Miller',
      dob: '1991-04-02'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Sophia',
      lastName: 'Davis',
      dob: '1987-09-14'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Daniel',
      lastName: 'Taylor',
      dob: '1998-01-31'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Ava',
      lastName: 'Anderson',
      dob: '1984-07-22'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Matthew',
      lastName: 'Moore',
      dob: '1996-12-07'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Isabella',
      lastName: 'Wilson',
      dob: '1989-03-18'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Ethan',
      lastName: 'White',
      dob: '1994-10-12'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Mia',
      lastName: 'Harris',
      dob: '1983-08-29'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Alexander',
      lastName: 'Martin',
      dob: '1992-02-05'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Emma',
      lastName: 'Thomas',
      dob: '1986-05-20'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'William',
      lastName: 'Clark',
      dob: '1997-09-03'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Sophia',
      lastName: 'Robinson',
      dob: '1981-11-26'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'James',
      lastName: 'Baker',
      dob: '1999-06-10'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Ava',
      lastName: 'Green',
      dob: '1980-01-15'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Benjamin',
      lastName: 'Adams',
      dob: '1990-07-30'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Olivia',
      lastName: 'Lee',
      dob: '1985-04-13'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Lucas',
      lastName: 'Hall',
      dob: '1993-10-28'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Amelia',
      lastName: 'Carter',
      dob: '1988-03-21'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Jackson',
      lastName: 'King',
      dob: '1995-12-16'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Ella',
      lastName: 'Ward',
      dob: '1982-08-07'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Liam',
      lastName: 'Turner',
      dob: '1991-01-22'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Grace',
      lastName: 'Scott',
      dob: '1986-06-06'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Logan',
      lastName: 'Evans',
      dob: '1998-04-01'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Chloe',
      lastName: 'Parker',
      dob: '1983-09-24'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Joel',
      lastName: 'Ferguson',
      dob: '1990-05-15'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Lenora',
      lastName: 'Young',
      dob: '1985-12-28'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Brandon',
      lastName: 'Wolfe',
      dob: '1993-08-03'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Jesus',
      lastName: 'Kelly',
      dob: '1988-02-17'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Alex',
      lastName: 'Norris',
      dob: '1995-11-09'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Leah',
      lastName: 'Holt',
      dob: '1982-06-25'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Frances',
      lastName: 'Campbell',
      dob: '1991-04-02'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'William',
      lastName: 'McLaughlin',
      dob: '1987-09-14'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Maude',
      lastName: 'Hansen',
      dob: '1998-01-31'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Gilbert',
      lastName: 'McCormick',
      dob: '1984-07-22'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Hunter',
      lastName: 'Hampton',
      dob: '1996-12-07'
    },
  ],
};

const PER_PAGE = 10;

const InfiniteScrollObserver = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState < {
    firstName: string;lastName: string;dob: string
  }[] > ([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);
  const [endIndex, setEndIndex] = useState(PER_PAGE);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  const observer = useRef < IntersectionObserver | null > (null);

  const loadMoreItems = () => {
    console.log(startIndex, endIndex); // always the same result, never changed
    console.log(page, 'page') // page is also always the same
    const newItems = patientResults.items.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    setItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...newItems]);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const lastItemElementRef = useCallback(
    (node: HTMLDivElement) => {
      if (loading) return;
      if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
      observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(
        (entries) => {
          if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
            setPage((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1);
            loadMoreItems();
          }
        }, {
          threshold: 0.1,
        }
      );
      if (node) observer.current.observe(node);
    }, [loading, hasMore]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMoreItems();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(startIndex, endIndex); // here is updated
    setHasMore(patientResults.items.length > items.length);
    setStartIndex((prevPage) => prevPage + PER_PAGE);
    setEndIndex((prevEndIndex) => prevEndIndex + PER_PAGE);
  }, [items]);

  return ( <
    Box className = "flex f-column i-center"
    width = {
      '90vw'
    } > {
      items.map((item, index) => {
        if (items.length === index + 1) {
          return ( <
            div key = {
              index
            }
            ref = {
              lastItemElementRef
            }
            className = "last-index"
            style = {
              {
                height: 150
              }
            } > {
              index + 1
            } {
              item.firstName
            } {
              item.lastName
            } - {
              item.dob
            } <
            /div>
          );
        } else {
          return ( <
            div key = {
              index
            }
            style = {
              {
                height: 150
              }
            } > {
              index + 1
            } {
              item.firstName
            } {
              item.lastName
            } - {
              item.dob
            } <
            /div>
          );
        }
      })
    } {
      loading ? ( <
        Box position = "fixed"
        bottom = {
          0
        }
        left = {
          0
        }
        width = {
          '100vw'
        }
        className = "flex j-center"
        bgcolor = {
          'text.secondary'
        }
        color = {
          'white'
        } >
        <
        p > Loading... < /p> < /
        Box >
      ) : ( <
        >
        <
        />
      )
    } <
    /Box>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScrollObserver;
```

I have problem in loadMoreItems function that startIndex & endIndex is always the same so every time on calling this function it returns the same items (first 10 items from patientResults).

[image]

So, like is shown in the image, on results 47-50 I am getting actually results from 7-10 from the patientResults.items array.

What is problem with state, why these states aren't updated in loadMoreItems() function?
Please help!